# Explanation of Arrays in Java and modifying outside of scope?

Tags: java, arrays, scope

I am confused why the hello method is able to affect the array declared in the main method. My understanding was it was outside of the scope.

```
public class Test {
    
    void hello(String i, int[] arr){
        i += "hello";
        arr[0] = 4;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test t = new Test();
        String i = "hey";
        int [] arr = {0,1,2,3};
        t.hello(i,arr);
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

returns

```
hey
[4, 1, 2, 3]
```

i would understand a return of "heyhello" or [0,1,2,3].

Comment: "i would understand a return of "heyhello" or [01234]" => Why? Java is always _pass-by-value_. So you can't manipulate the argument variables that were used when calling a method.

Comment: That means, that in your main method, the variables `i` and `arr` will always refer to the same object after the method call as they did before. The only thing is, that one element of the arry is manipulated inside the hello method.

Comment: Ralf provided a good answer — one other point of possible confusion is that your parameters to `hello` and your variables in `main` are using the same names. This is allowed and works fine, but can be a little confusing. Try changing the names of the parameters, say `void hello(String s, int[] integers)` and read Ralf's answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's an important difference between `String` and `int[]`.

Both are so-called "reference objects", meaning that they hava a unique identity, and can be referenced from variables, fields, method arguments etc.

So, `t.hello(i,arr)` passes two arguments into the `hello()` method:

- a reference to a `String` with content `"hey"`
- a reference to an `int[]` array with content `{0,1,2,3}`.

Inside `hello()`, you "modify" both variables, but differently:

- With `i += "hello";`, you append a word to the end of the string. The Java designers decided to make strings "immutable", so you can't change a `String` object that has been created, you can only create a new string in such a case. That means that the original string (that the `i` variable from `main()` still references) will not be affected. It's only the `i` inside `hello()` that now references the fresh, longer string. And `main()` still has its `i` being `"hey"`.
- With `arr[0] = 4;`, you set the first array element to a different value. Arrays have been defined differently, they are mutable. For an existing array, you can modify its elements without the need for a fresh copy. So, there's still only one array in use, and its first element has been modified. When `main()` prints its `arr` array, it is the identical array that has been modified inside `hello()`, und thus contains the number `4`.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code is demonstrating the difference between passing mutable objects and immutable objects as parameters.

The array arr is passed to hello as an argument. That means the pointer to the arr object is copied and the copy is given to hello, so hello has a pointer to the array declared in the main method. Arrays are mutable and hello has a reference to it,, nothing stops hello from changing the contents of arr.

The string i gets passed into hello similarly, hello gets a copy of the pointer. The hello method replaces the string referred to by its copy of the pointer (since strings are immutable), but the pointer used by the main method is unaffected and still points to the original value of i.